# How to add a class to an admin form input?

Tags: magento2, forms, uicomponent

I'm building my own add/edit form in the backend for a Magento 2 module using ui-components.
I have one simple thing to do... add a class to an input/select/textarea.
Here is my element definition:

```
<field name="name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">author</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
            <item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enter full name here</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

This is rendered as

```
<div class="admin__field _required" data-bind="css: $data.additionalClasses, attr: {'data-index': index}, visible: visible" data-index="name">
    <!-- ko if: $data.label --><label class="admin__field-label" data-bind="attr: {for: uid}, visible: $data.labelVisible" for="LLKEGUU">
        <span data-bind="attr: {'data-config-scope': $data.scopeLabel}, i18n: label">Name</span>
    </label><!-- /ko -->
    <div class="admin__field-control" data-bind="css: {'_with-tooltip': $data.tooltip, '_with-reset': $data.showFallbackReset &amp;&amp; $data.isDifferedFromDefault}">
        <!-- ko ifnot: hasAddons() --><!-- ko template: elementTmpl -->
<input class="admin__control-text" data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled
    }" name="name" aria-describedby="notice-LLKEGUU" id="LLKEGUU" type="text">
<!-- /ko --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: hasAddons() --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.tooltip --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.showFallbackReset && $data.isDifferedFromDefault --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: error --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.notice --><div class="admin__field-note" data-bind="attr: {id: noticeId}" id="notice-LLKEGUU">
            <span data-bind="i18n: notice">Enter full name here</span>
        </div><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.additionalInfo --><!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: $data.hasService() --><!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add a class `my-custom-css-class` to the field itself or the element wrapping it (the one with the class `admin__field-control`) or even the wrapper of the wrapper (the one with the class `admin__field _required`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `additionalClasses` :

```
<item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">my-custom-class</item>
```

Side note: interestingly, it seems like it also handles arrays:

```
<item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="my-custom-class" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks. I would rather have it on the field itself, but I can work with this.

Comment: @Marius unfortunately apart from using some custom JS I don't think it's possible on the field itself out of the box. You can check by looking at `Magento/Ui/view/base/web/templates/form/element/input.html` that it does not support custom class

Comment: Yeah...I just found that file. Too bad. Anyway, I can work with this. It's better than nothing.

Comment: @Marius time for PR ? :P

Answer (score 4):

We cannot add a class to input, textarea, etc. We need to add a new custom template for the elements, like this:

```
<field name="position" sortOrder="90" formElement="input">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="classes" xsi:type="string">CUSTOM_CLASS</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Position</label>
        <dataType>number</dataType>
        <elementTmpl>VENDOR_MODULE/form/element/input</elementTmpl>
        <dataScope>position</dataScope>
    </settings>
</field>
```

**VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/web/template/form/element/input.html**

```
<input type="text"
    data-bind="
        event: {change: userChanges},
        value: value,
        hasFocus: focused,
        valueUpdate: valueUpdate,
        attr: {
            name: inputName,
            placeholder: placeholder,
            'aria-describedby': noticeId,
            id: uid,
            disabled: disabled,
            class: 'admin__control-text ' + $data.classes
    }"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I already use:

```
<field name="password" sortOrder="80">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Teledoc_Supplier/form/element/password</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Password</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">password</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
    <field name="password_confirmation" sortOrder="90">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Teledoc_Supplier/form/element/password-confirm</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Confirm Password</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">password_confirmation</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="equalTo" xsi:type="string">.password-supplier</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

in the html:
Teledoc_Supplier/form/element/password-confirm

```
<input class="input-text admin__control-text" type="password" data-bind="
hasFocus: focused,
value: value,
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    'aria-describedby': noticeId,
    id: uid,
    disabled: disabled
}" data-validate="{equalTo:'.password-supplier'}"/>
```

Teledoc_Supplier/form/element/password

```
<input class="input-text admin__control-text password-supplier" type="password" data-bind="
hasFocus: focused,
value: value,
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    'aria-describedby': noticeId,
    id: uid,
    disabled: disabled
}"/>
```